# Запятая в предложении "Сквозь туман вечерней зари(,) слушать дальние песни ветра"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Сквозь туман вечерней зари(,)
>   Слушать дальние песни ветра.

Нужна ли запятая в данном предложении?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Запятая не нужна, распространенное обстоятельство "сквозь туман вечерней зари" входит в основное сообщение и не обособляется (нет причин для обособления).

Похожий текст:

"Сквозь вечерний туман мне под небом стемневшим
 Слышен крик журавлей всё ясней и ясней".

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна, здесь нечего обособлять или разделять.